# How to view current schema search path in a h2 database?

Tags: schema, h2, search-path

When connecting to an h2 database, the default search path is set to `public`.
You can alter it with the `SET SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH`.

But if you alter it multiple times, at some point how can you view its current content?

I wasn't able to find some kind of commands like this `VIEW SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH` or `SHOW SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH`.

Typing them give me error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit a hack, but you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_STATE 
WHERE KEY='SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH'
```

Comment: It's really a hack but it does the job pretty well ^^

Answer (score 0):

Non-hack solution:
SELECT SCHEMA()

Comment: I tried connecting with this url: `jdbc:h2:mem:;INIT=create schema if not exists po;SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH=PO,INFORMATION_SCHEMA,PUBLIC`. `SELECT SCHEMA()` returned only PUBLIC whereas Thomas' solution printed the expected schema search_path. **h2 1.4.193**

Comment: Agreed, search path isn't the same as current schema and may include multiple schemas. Current schema is important when you execute some DDL, for SELECTs search_path is more relevant.